# How to find a subset of "most different" vectors (from a set of multi-dimensional vectors)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors

I am given a set of multi-dimensional vectors (e.g. 7D) and I need to select a subset of maximally "different" ones, in the sense of "pointing in as many different directions as possible" and "maximising the spread of the selected vectors". (I'm not really sure what the correct terminology for this would be, so I'm using the least technical description I can.) This is illustrated in 2D in the figure below, where the thick black vectors on the right are one possible answer, given the input vectors shown on the left.

I primarily need to know what mathematical criterion I can use, and I can deal with the ensuing numerical optimisation problem myself--however, if there is a known algorithm for solving this problem, of course I'd appreciate a reference to it as well.

Thanks!

[image: example in 2D]

Comment: I think this is the same as linearly independent vectors,as you're essentially looking for vectors that contain the most non-redundant information from a set. If a vector can be expressed as a linear combination of the others, it does not add any coverage which the other vectors didn't have, if that makes sense

That would mean you're looking for the maximal subset of linearly independent vectors

Comment: Let $N$ be the number of vectors. Would this not then be solved by $N$ points uniformly distributed on the unit ball?